# unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Developer

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign

I have been unsettled by this issue for the past 3 days and none of the solutions in any forum has been of any help.

```
Error: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Developer"
```

I am extremely disturbed because of this issue. I really need help.

Comment: I understand that you need to leave the Trust Settings as System Default. Its basically delete the certificates and rebuild them This seems to have an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307416/xcode-ios-app-development-code-signing

Answer (score 1):

## Xcode 12.4

It seems like a hack but it works!

1. Go to Xcode preferences and **Export Apple ID and Code Signing Assets...**
   [image: Settings]
2. Set a password for the export

> ⚠️ You are going to delete all passwords and profiles! Don't forget your password! Writing down your password is highly recommended.

> ⛔️ This file will contain all your accounts and profiles. Make sure to keep it very secure.

3. Delete all accounts.
4. Build and face the new error.
5. Import them back using your password.

It's working again.

Answer (score 0):

Remote building an iOS application from Windows failed with this error.
The following steps solved the issue:

1. Open `Keychain Access.app`.
2. In the left bar, go to `System`.
3. Drag the [2030 Apple certificate](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer) (that should be missing) into the window and enter your password to add it. You should now have two Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authorities in your keychain, one expiring in 2023 and the other in 2030.