# Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Developer ID Application: xxxxxx: errSecInternalComponent

Tags: code-signing, codesign

I am trying to migrate our build server to a new machine.
I exported the certificate and imported it on the new machine.
But when I get error when I am trying to run codesign

```
Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Developer ID Application: xxxxxxx"./workspace/onCourseServer.app: errSecInternalComponent
```

I tried deleting the certificate and reimporting it, adding `always trust`; I also tried regenerating the certificate and using the new certificate on the new mac. But none of them worked. I am still getting the same error.

The new mac is running the mojave.

Comment: Duplicate question ...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307416/xcode-ios-app-development-code-signing

Comment: I understand that you need to leave the Trust Settings as System Default - setting to Always Trust won't work Duplicate question ...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307416/xcode-ios-app-development-code-signing