# Codesign issue for the Project

Tags: ios, macos, keychain, codesign

This question has been asked [Xcode Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 : errSecInternalComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023639/xcode-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-errsecinternalcomponen) and [Xcode ios app development code signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307416/xcode-ios-app-development-code-signing)
and I followed every answer given there but no luck for me.

The issue started when I got a new certificate, and I added it in the keychain and removed the older one. Now I am getting the following error.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending the entire night, I finally got the fix.

Open the Keychain and check if any of the Certificates are having + symbol. Double click and set it to "Use System Defaults" rather than "Always Trust".

That's it.

Edit:

The Keychain window as of now you see couple of items having a blue-plus, because they are set to "Always Trust". Change it to "System Defaults" by double clicking and editing its value, it will ask the keychain password for verfication.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information?  I have been through the keychain many times, and I don't see where my Certificates would show a + symbol.  Is this in the Access Control page that opens when I double click on the certificate?